# Using Where expression on UIElementCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, xaml

I'm converting a Silverlight app to WPF. The following piece of code didn't compile but it does in Silverlight:

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="Table">
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
foreach (var uiElement in Table.Children
            .Where(x => Grid.GetColumn((Border)x) == Table.ColumnDefinitions.Count() - 1))
{
   //do something
}
```

At `Where` it says

> 'UIElementCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no
>   extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type
>   'UIElementCollection' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

`System.Linq` namespace is added.

If I cast `UIElementCollection` to an `IList<object>` then it works, but I receive a warning:

> it's a suspicious cast

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight marked as duplicate?! My question is better explained. Do you expect me to first find that question? No way! The questions have a complete different context... And also, people who search on Google will find this question easily than the other one.

Comment: To me, if both questions ran into the same problem, and both questions have exactly the same solution, then one is a duplicate of the other. A quick search for `UIElementCollection` with `[linq]` tag turns up the other question within the top five hits, so it wasn't too hard to. Some duplicates are better worded than their earlier counterparts. That's why SO keeps many duplicates around - it makes solutions easier to find if you come from an outside search engine. That's why I upvoted the question and an answer that I think works best.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Silverlight, the `UIElementCollection` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, but the [`UIElementCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) in WPF implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`. If you want to use LINQ here, you can 
use [`OfType<UIElement>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) as an option:

```
foreach (var uiElement in Table.Children.OfType<UIElement>()
           .Where(x => Grid.GetColumn((Border)x) == Table.ColumnDefinitions.Count() - 1))
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that [`UIElementCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) does not implement the generic `IEnumerable<T>` :

```
public class UIElementCollection : IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

While the [`Enumerable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method requires the generic version:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate
)
```

So, the solution is to cast the elements first:

```
foreach (var uiElement in Table.Children.OfType<UIElement>().Where(x => Grid.GetColumn((Border)x) == Table.ColumnDefinitions.Count() - 1))
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't compile because [UIElementCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) implements the non-generic collection interfaces, and Linq requires the generic collection interfaces.

You can use the [Cast<T>()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get an instance of `IEnumerable<T>` and then use Linq:

```
var children = Table.Children.Cast<UIElement>();
foreach (var uiElement in children .Where(x => Grid.GetColumn((Border)x) == Table.ColumnDefinitions.Count() - 1))
{
   //do something
}
```